# Retrieve old Evolution address book

Tags: evolution

How can I retrieve Evolution's address book from an old install?

I used the backup/restore feature of Evolution after an upgrade, but the restore was giving me problems so I had to wipe out the .evolution folders and start over.

How can I get hold of my old address book from the original .evolution folder? The files are in the .db format, and I can't import them from within evolution.

I tried deleting the current address book folder (/.local/share/evolution/addressbook) and replacing it with the original folder, but the address book does not get loaded by Evolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to kill evolution server before copying the old files.

You can open Gnome System Monitor and kill **e-addressbook-factory**.

After that, delete current address book and copy the new files. There are two evolution folders: .local/share/evolution and .local/config/evolution, I'm not sure if you need to move both (that's what I did).

Comment: thanks, it was enough to replace the addressbook folder in .local/share/evolution

Answer (score 0):

If that does not work, you can find an alternative solution [in this posting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146327/evolution-data-migration-on-update-missed-all-but-the-first-accounts-mail) -- which even allows you to import single addresses from an old .db file (not the new SQLite format).