# Copying Evolution emails from Ubuntu 10.10 to 12.10

Tags: evolution, restore

I originally had a dual boot configuration of Ubuntu 10.10 and Windows 7.

Suddenly, something happened and I got black screen. I managed to copy my home folder via an Ubuntu live CD.

I then installed Ubuntu 12.10, installed Evolution, and copied the `~/.evolution` and `~/.gconf/apps/evolution` folders from my backup to my new installation.

After that, I started Evolution and made the first steps, but I am unable to get my emails back.

How do I restore Evolution emails from a backup make from Ubuntu 10.10 to Ubuntu 12.10?

---

Comment: I have Evolution installed but don't have an `~/.evolution` or `~/.gconf/app/evolution` folder at all. My guess is that the version of Evolution used back in Ubuntu 10.10 stored its emails in a different format than the new version in Ubuntu 12.10 does.

Comment: I don't have an `~/.gconf/app` folder; instead, it is named `~/.gconf/apps`. Maybe Ubuntu 10.10 was different - are you sure that is correct or is it a typo?

Answer (score 1):

The Evolution data structure has changed quite a lot -- the directory `.evolution` is no longer used. If you made a backup ***from within Evolution*** before upgrading, you should be able to restore it (hopefully). Otherwise it will be a bit troublesome:

E-Mail accounts are faster to re-configure (if you used IMAP, data is still on the server. People using POP3 will not have this option to regain their mails).

Other options can be found in several questions on this site, e.g.:

- [Evolution data migration (on update) missed all but the first “accounts” (mail, addressbook, calendar…)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146327/68291)
- [Questions containing '[evolution] migration'](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%5Bevolution%5D+migration)

Basically, Evolution currently stores its configuration in 3 different folders:

- `.local/share/evolution`
- `.local/config/evolution`
- `.gconf/apps/evolution`

But not only the location has changed, formats are also different (e.g. address books now use SQLite databases).